# How to use dynamic_pointer_cast on shared_ptr<shared_ptr<B>>?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have two classes `Band` and `BandElectron` where `Band` is the baseclass of `BandElectron`. now i have

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<BandElectron>> pd;

shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Band>> pb = dynamic_pointer_cast<shared_ptr<Band>>(pd);
```

which gives me the following compiler error:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<Band>; _Up = std::shared_ptr<BandElectron>]’:                                                                                                              
src/simulation/dynamic/one_material/tsibidis_explicit.cpp:57:80:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr.h:514:23: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘(& __r)->std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<BandElectron> >::<anonymous>.std::__shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<BandElectron>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::get()’ (of type ‘using element_type = std::remove_extent<std::shared_ptr<BandElectron> >::type*’ {aka ‘class std::shared_ptr<BandElectron>*’}) to type ‘using element_type = using element_type = std::remove_extent<std::shared_ptr<Band> >::type*’ {aka ‘class std::shared_ptr<Band>*’} (source type is not polymorphic)                                                                                                      
       if (auto* __p = dynamic_cast<typename _Sp::element_type*>(__r.get()))
```

How do i do a dynamic cast of a shared_ptr to a shared_ptr?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<anythinghere>>` looks like a big red flag to me.

Comment: First of all you're missing a closing `>`. Secondly, `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Band>>` versus `shared_ptr<Band>`?

Comment: I know but i'm not the person to decide this. Just the one to work with it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast#Example) has some useful example code.

Comment: Lastly, what you're trying to do is not really possible. If we use normal pointers instead, then `Band**` is different from `BandElectron**` no matter how `Band` and `BandElectron` are related. `BandElectron*` (single pointer) can be up-casted to `Band*`, and `Band*` might be down-casted to `BandElectron*`, but the double-pointer makes it very different.